# Git Rebase with remote branch

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have two branches:

1. the **master** branch which has 5 commits (A,B,C,D,E)
2. the **feature** branch which I created from commit C and which has the commits F and G.
   I also already pushed the two branches (master and feature) to the remote repository.
   So the graphs on the local and the remote look like the following:

   ```
   A - B - C - D - E <-master
           |
           | - F - G <-feature
   ```

But now I want to rebase the branch **feature** on top of branch **master** using the following 2 command lines:

```
     git checkout feature
     git rebase master
```

So in local, I will have the following graph:

```
    A - B - C - D - E <-master
                    |
                    | - F1 - G1 <-feature
```

But if then I do git push, will the remote repo be identical to the local one without any pb (I work alone in the project, so normally I will not have any pb because of the history which is rewritten)?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it will.... the only thing is that it will be a forced push because of the rewrite.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is the first time I do a rebase on a big project, and I needed someone to confirm the idea, and also confirm that the master branch will not be  modified at all